# What is the term when a non diatonic chord ends a musical phrase?

Tags: theory, piano, terminology

Is it still considered a cadence? For example a 1,6,4,b5,1 progression in c major, it might sound wacky but i am just curious if there is a term for it. Also are there cadences for the 2,3,6,7 chords of a key?

Comment: Cadences generally consist of the last two chords, very occasionally they may need the one before. It doesn't matter what key a cadence is in (you mention C, but they're all the same). Otherwise it's an interesting question.

Comment: I don't understand how a I chord (the end chord in the example) is non diatonic.

Comment: @ToddWilcox - I think the OP means the cadence itself, ending as ever with a diatonic, but the penultimate chord being non-diatonic.  bV>I may have some tts about it. I sometimes use #V>I, and guess it will have been named. It's what we do!

Comment: The only tonal cadence I'm aware of that ends with motion by tritone (which is b5 -> 1) would be half-cadence with a [Neopolitan 6th](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neapolitan_chord) chord, which IMO sounds pretty cool.

Answer (score 1):

This is only a partial answer, as I don't know a term for the b5-I sequence.

As to your second question, there is an answer of sorts:  any sequence that ends V or V7-x, where x is anything other than I, is called a Deceptive Cadence, especially in the case of V-vi.  A V-ii cadence would sound a wee bit odd, but would still be considered Deceptive, and likewise for the last example you gave, though I must say I hope hope hope I NEVER hear a V-viio sequence!

Comment: I wonder if "deceptive cadence" is new (or locale-specific). Forty years ago in the UK, this was called an [interrupted cadence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cadence_(music)#Interrupted_.28deceptive.29_cadence), most often V-vi, but can apply to any unexpected resolution.

Comment: Well, it was in most music theory books back in the 1950s, and they called it that at Juilliard when I went there in the late 1960s, but perhaps it has become obsolete or archaic.  But that's what I've always called it, and it's what I've always heard it called.

Comment: @AndrewLeach There is a considerable difference between American and British terminology in music theory. Unfortunately (for the British) the American system is more widely used. Deceptive cadence is simply the American term.